# NSTextBlock backgroundColor is not drawn

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa, nstextview, textkit

I have an `NSTextBlock` subclass that has a specific `backgroundColor` set. Now when I add a custom paragraph style to a range of text like this

```
let block = MyTextBlock()
block.backgroundColor = myBackgroundColor

let pstyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
pstyle.textBlocks = [block]

attributedText.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: pstyle, range: textRange)

// Append the attributed string to the text views textStorage ...
```

the text block is shown without a background color. I know that the text blocks works, because `rectForLayout` gets called, but when I try to override `drawBackground` it never gets called.

Do I have to do something else for `NSTextBlock`s to draw their background?

PS: Borders also seem to be ignored. I also tried to find a sample on [Github](https://github.com/mortenjust/nstextblock-test), but that also doesn't draw any backgrounds, despite having a background color set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying everything, I finally managed to get the background to show up, by setting

```
setValue(100, type: .percentageValueType, for: .width)
```

It seems that the drawing logic expects some value for the content size. Really nice documentation job there. This requirement is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Thanks for this – I gave up working with NSTextBlocks after not being able to set the background, even though it seemed possible. Will give it another try now.